# Html Form to send email. How to delete '+' character for 'space'

Tags: html, email, forms, thunderbird

I am using the following workaround to let a user send a mail to my client:

```
<form action="mailto:mail@domain.tld" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
    <input name="subject" type="hidden" value="Request to offer #5" />
    <input type="submit" value="Email me" />
</form>
```

But on Ubuntu 14.04 (my workspace) it opens Thunderbird and the subject is 'Request+to+offer+#5'. I tried different enctypes (none and multipart/form-data) and methods(post and get) and pre-encoding the subject with '+' and '%20'. But with the post-method Thunderbird puts the post-string 'subject=Request+to+offer+#5' in the body and the other ways leave the subject as I put it into my form or even empty.
How do I fix this?

Requirements:

- Button that looks on every system as the system's button.
- Predefined subject
- Works with every email client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you get the plusses is a bug ([bug 1055950](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1055950)).

To make it work you can, however, create a button like

```
<button onclick="window.location='mailto:mail@domain.tld?subject=request%20to%20offer'">Email me</button>
```

Comment: Didn't thought it could been a bug on the Thunderbird side. Would it be a big difference whether I use the button-tag and javascript or the form-tag?

Comment: Yes. You don't necessaryily have to use a <button>, but you have to create the mailto url yourself, handling encoding of spaces manually.